# Node.js apache bench test

Tags: node.js, performance-testing, apachebench

Playing and trying to see how fast node.js can serve a static file from disk using apache bench

```
ab -r -n 10000 -c 1000 http://server:8080/loadtestfile.txt
```

I've got ulimit problem on Ubuntu 11.04 x64 VirtualBox VM on OSX Lion

```
(node) Hit max file limit. Increase "ulimit - n"
```

I can't increase the limit anymore.

```
$ ulimit -n 1000000
$ limit -n 1100000
-su: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

Is this the right way to force node.js to reload the file from disk to serve each HTTP request? How do I increase the limit beyond 1000000?

Normal curl request works:

```
curl http://server:8080/loadtestfile.txt
```

Code

```
var sys = require('sys'),
http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
index;

http.createServer(function(request, response) {

fs.readFile('./loadtestfile.txt', function (err, data) {

    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write(data);
    response.end();
 });

}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, your application would run within the limits given to it; it should cleanly handle `accept(2)` returning an error condition with `errno(3)` set to `EMFILE` or `ENFILE` by not trying to accept another connection until an existing connection dies.

However, fixing the application to handle this case gracefully can be difficult; if you just want to raise your limits further to do more testing, there are two possibilities.

- Edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` to raise the hard limit for your user account for the `nofile` limit to something much higher and then log in your user account again.
- Do your testing in a root shell; you could either log in as `root` directly or use `sudo -s` or `su` to start the shell, then run the `ulimit -n` command from there.

The difficulty is because *raising limits* requires administrative access. (When you've got a few hundred users on the system simultaneously, you want to keep them playing nice...)

However, I'm going to guess that your application will *also* run into the system-wide maximum number of open files limit; that is configured via `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`. Raise that limit too, if the application complains.